# Quand les expressions « de sorte que / de façon que / de manière que » demandent-elles le subjonctif ?

Tags: subjonctif, mode-grammatical

On apprend à l'école que ces tournures exigent le subjonctif, mais on m'avait dit qu'il y a des cas où l'indicatif doit être utilisé. Est-ce que cela est dû au sens, ou au contexte ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Voici le paragraphe correspondant du Bon usage :

> ***De manière que, de façon que, de sorte que***  impliquent une
> conséquence, réalisée ou non. Si elle est réalisée, on met l’indicatif
> ; si elle ne l’est pas (ce qui revient à une idée de but), on met le
> subjonctif :
>
> *Il a partagé les gâteaux de manière que tout le monde
> **est** satisfait. Il a partagé les gâteaux de manière que tout le monde
> **soit** satisfait.*  — *Élisa assurait […] qu’il y avait moyen d’arranger
> la chose, de manière que sa mère n’**eût** pas le moindre soupçon* (E. de
> Gonc., Fille Élisa, v). — *On attachait leurs mains […] à un poteau
> ou à une colonne, de façon que leur nudité **était** divulguée au peuple
> entier, et pour qu’elles fussent en butte aux insultes* (Pieyre de
> Mand., Motocyclette, F°, p. 190). [Propos. de manière coordonnée à une
> propos. de but.]

Comment: Aloes, est-ce que vous voulez dire.. "De sorte que tout le monde soit satisfait" - c'est l'intention pour laquelle il a partagé .. "De sorte que tout le monde est satisfait"- c'est la raison tout le monde était satisfait ????